# grep -f does not find files in loop

Tags: grep

I want to use grep -f in a loop but it's not seeing the files I give to -f. My grep version from `grep -V`:

```
grep (GNU grep) 3.6
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Example:

```
echo "line1" > searchfile.1
echo "line2" > searchfile.2
echo "line1" > targetfile
for file in `ls searchfile*`; do echo $file; ls $file; grep -f $file targetfile; done
```

gives the output

```
searchfile.1
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[0m'$'\033''[32msearchfile.1'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
grep: searchfile.1: No such file or directory
searchfile.2
ls: cannot access ''$'\033''[32msearchfile.2'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
grep: searchfile.2: No such file or directory
```

But if I do it manually like

```
grep -f searchfile.1 targetfile
```

I get

```
line1
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Doesn't look like a grep issue at all. Would you mind adding `ls $file;` to the for loop?

Comment: Don't parse `ls` output, use `find`.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson I added `ls $file`. I do not understand the output

Comment: @TimurShtatland that worked! Can you explain why parsing `ls` output didn't work?

Comment: @Matt I don't think the code you executed actually looked exactly like what you posted as there's no explanation for that output given that code. In particular the output you posted looks like you were trying to use `ls` on the output of ` `grep` command that colorized it's output, hence the escape chars etc. In general, though, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Oh and wrt your statement `I want to use grep -f in a loop` - it seems unlikely that that'll be the best approach to whatever it is you're trying to do. Post a new question if you'd like help with whatever that is. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes btw as learning how to use quotes correctly will greatly improve your shell programming.

Comment: @EdMorton you're right, I forgot I have my `ls` defined as an alias to `ls -p --color`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't parse `ls` output, use `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'searchfile*' -exec echo {} \; -exec grep -f {} targetfile \;
```

Output:

```
./searchfile.2
./searchfile.1
line1
```

---

`ls` outputs other characters in addition to the file names (for the colored `ls` output). Plus, there may be whitespace in the file names (not in your case, though). See also:
Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)? - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/13411

Comment: Nice catch! Could also use ordinary wildcard expansion provided by the shell: `for file in searchfile*; do ...`

Answer (score 2):

Two alternatives to Timur Shatland's `find` solution.

1. Use shell wildcard expansion

```
for file in searchfile*; do ...
```

2. Work around the `ls` alias by putting it inside quotes

```
for file in `"ls" searchfile*`; do ...
```